# RESTful service response should be splited into pieces

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, response, hypermedia

I want to get first `20` records, I have response time as `200`

After some time (By calling the same service) I want another `20` records. 
By each hit I want to get `20` records. How can I implement this?

I am using Spring ,hibernate and angular as front-end.

Please provide a solution .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [spring-data-rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/), you should be able to expose your hibernate entity to the user in a RESTful way. Using the auto generated end points you should be able to perform POST/PUT/GET/DELETE. When you expose the entity, the pagination is by default available for you.

By making use of spring-data-rest your scenario could be solved by giving a page size in the (GET) REST response

**Example:**

For instance assume that you have 200 user records in your DB and you want server 20 records per request,then the GET REST URL will be look like this:

http://localhost:8080/users?page=1&size=5

There are 2 key information to be noted:

```
page - the page number to access (0 indexed, defaults to 0).
size - the page size requested (defaults to 20).
```

So to get first 20 records, user will issue a request like:
http://localhost:8080/users or http://localhost:8080/users?page=0&size=20

To access next 20 items, change the page number alone: http://localhost:8080/users?page=1

Since default size is 20, in you case you can omit that; but if you decide to modify the size, say 25 or 30, then you should be able to supply that as part of size param.

Comment: How Can I get second 20 data.? If I give 20 as a size. It will always return first 20 data. Am I rite ?

Comment: Added an example. please let me know if you need more clarification.